# How to Specify Font-Size for PDF report Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, config, font-size

In my Rails app, I am using wkhtmltopdf for PDF generation and the the configuration settings are defined in '`config/initializers/pdfkit_config.rb`'. You can see the code below.

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = '/home/user/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'
  config.default_options = {
    :encoding=>"UTF-8",
    :page_size=>"A4",
    :margin_top=>"0.25in",
    :margin_right=>"1in",
    :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
    :margin_left=>"1in",
    :disable_smart_shrinking=>false
    }

end
```

Can we define the font-size for the report here? Thanks :)-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem uses the tool [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), and merely passes in options that that tool will accept.  Since it's a HTML to PDF sort of tool, you should specify the font size using CSS.

Comment: Can't we send the font-size as an option to the tool?

Comment: Doesn't look like it.  Of course, both the gem you're using and the tool it's calling are open source so you can modify them to suit your needs if you'd like, but it would be *much* easier to just modify your css.